# How to deselect JMenu after exiting a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am implementing a `JMenu` in a `JMenuBar` which, when clicked, opens a `JOptionPane` (user inputs text, though irrelevant to the problem). After exiting the option pane, however, the menu is still selected, and if the user scrolls to another menu, that is selected as well.

I've tried using `.setSelected(false)` to the first menu clicked, but that doesn't prevent the next menus from getting selected. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: Here is an example of code:

```
JMenu menu= new JMenu("");
menuBar.add(menu);
menu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name: ");

            if(input!=null) {
                JMenuItem port = new JMenuItem();
                port.setText(input);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Comment: Try wrapping the code that displays the JOptionPane in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This way the menu should get a chance to repaint itself before the option pane is displayed.

Comment: Using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() resolves the selection problem, but doesn't let me create/edit my "input" string for my if-statement directly below it. Unless there's a different implementation I should use?

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: I found a workaround: add a JButton to the JMenuBar instead. I guess it makes more sense to use a button if I don't intend to add any menu items.